# No sound device after update from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have updated from 16.04 to 18.04 today (figured it's now been around for long enough to not have any annoying issues any more), but have run into the problem of my sound card (or whatever it's called these days) not being detected aby more...

I tried removing alsa and pulseaudio, installing it again etc. (the usual stuff), but my device still is not being detected.

[image: No device available]

It worked perfectly OK prior to the upgrade.

Oddly, Alsa sees some devices:
[image: Alsa sees devices]

It should be noted that I chose to continue using Unity instead of Gnome, but I keep getting the same exact result in Gnome, too.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved it. Just wanted to leave the solution here, as someone else might encounter the same.
After some more hours of wresting with it, I turned my attention to pulseaudio, and executed the following:

```
rm -r ~/.config/pulse; pulseaudio -k
```

That actually failed with an error, so I was about to give up, but found a hint somewhere else that suggested running the following command:

```
pulseaudio -D
```

After doing so and rebooting the device list got properly populated and I was able to select a working device :).

Solved!